# xampp mysql could not be started

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

so xampp is saying [mysql] error: MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly when i try to start. checking error log and got the below log.

`````
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background log and ibuf IO write threads.
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Checksum mismatch in datafile: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 0
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2021-12-25  8:04:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting ````

this happens after power failure and server restarts it self.

i try to recover by using innodb_force_recovery = 1,2,3,4,5,6 but got no luck.

please Help me out. Thanks!!!

N.B - Windows Server Environment.
`````

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the file at path  'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' and restart xamp

Comment: Its also disable all db using innodb engine.